# Increase the size of a region bounded by GPS coords

Tags: perl, google-maps, gps

I have a webapp in which I query for results that are nearby the user. Because of the way the app works, the user is located in a square bounded by 4 points, 2 for the bottom left corner and 2 for the upper right corner: latsw,latne,longsw,longne.
I need to increase the size of the "square" while keeping the user in the center of the square. I've been trying with basic stuff like:

```
$latsw= $latsw - $increasing_factor;
$latne= $latne + $increasing_factor;
$longsw=$longsw - $increasing_factor;
$longne=$longne + $increasing_factor;
```

and

```
$latsw= $latsw / $increasing_factor;
$latne= $latne * $increasing_factor;
$longsw=$longsw / $increasing_factor;
$longne=$longne * $increasing_factor;
```

but the results are just giving me a shifted area or some other weird behavior. I guess this is because GPS coords don't really behave linearly in a 2D plane. Any ideas to do something like this while keeping it relatively simple?

Comment: Now that I think about it, there is not really much coding per se in this question, so if anyone feels this should go in another site, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

You want to keep the same center longitude/latitude, so calculate that first (by averaging 
the two longitudes and two latitudes you already have):

```
center_long = (ne_long + sw_long)/2
center_lat = (ne_lat + sw_lat)/2
```

Then calculate the size of the bounding box by differencing the two longitudes and 
two latitudes to get delta_long, delta_lat.

```
delta_long = ne_long - sw_long
delta_lat = ne_lat - sw_lat
```

Adjust delta_long and delta_lat by multiplying by some factor (say, 1.5 for a 50% increase):

```
new_delta_long = delta_long * increasing_factor
new_delta_lat = delta_lat * increasing_factor
```

Finally calculate the new bounding points:

```
new_corner_long = center_long +/- new_delta_long
new_corner_lat = center_lat +/- new_delta_lat
```

As long as you're not too close to the poles, equator, or prime meridian (to avoid awkward range/sign issues), or not using too large a bounding box (to avoid awkward deviations from 2-d plane behavior) this should get you in the ballpark of what you're looking for.